# How to remove Add button from Admin Grid conditionally?

Tags: grid, magento-1.9.3.6

I want to remove "Add new" Button from Admin Grid conditionally. Condition is if it has flag for adding then button will display otherwise not

Kindly help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to shed light on how the `Add New` button in the `Catalog -> Product` grid is displayed and what can be maybe done about it.

If you open file

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product
```

you will notice that this class extends

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container
```

This `Container` class provides the method

```
_addButton()
```

which as its first parameter accepts string: the button ID.

So, take a look at the method prepareLayout and you will notice

```
$this->_addButton('add_new', array(
        'label'   => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Add Product'),
        'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/*/new')}')",
        'class'   => 'add'
    ));
```

After this the button id is: `add_new`

The `Container` class also provides a method

```
_removeButton()
```

which accepts only one attribute: the button ID

This given, you should probably override the block that defines the button.

In more details, override the _prepareLayout method and use the `_addButton` conditionally in the first place (so you don't have to remove at all).

Or in other cases, where applicable, just call

```
$this->_removeButton($button_id)
```

In my example it would be

```
$this->_removeButton("add_new")
```

Of course, you can enclose this code in `IF` statement with whatever condition you need.

Comment: You are very welcome! :)